# Create Procedure with no Parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, database-cursor

Its my second time writing procedures and this one is the first time I have to use a cursor. For this procedure I am not expected to use parameters but Im having problems with it. This is what I currently have:

```
Create or Replace Procedure Update_Balance as

Cursor C1 is 
Select purchases.Cust_ID, Purchase_Amount, curr_balance,
credit_line,Pending_Flag 
from Purchases
inner join customers on purchases.cust_id = customers.cust_id
where purchases.pending_flag = 1
for update of curr_balance;

PendingBalance purchases.purchase_amount%type;

PurchaseRow c1%RowType;

ProposedNewBalance purchases.purchase_amount%type;

Begin
Begin
Open C1;
Fetch c1 into PurchaseRow;

While c1% Found Loop 

Select sum(Purchase_amount)
into PendingBalance
from purchases
where cust_id = c1.cust_id
and pending_flag = 1;
end; 

ProposedNewBalance := PendingBalance + c1.curr_balance;

If ProposedNewBalance > C1.Credit_Line then
dbms_output.put_line('One or more purchases were not processed for     Customer');
end if;

If ProposedNewBalance <= c1.Credit_Line then 
update Customers
set curr_balance = ProposedNewBalance
where customer.cust_id = c1.cust_id;
end if;

If ProposedNewBalance <= c1.credit_line then
Update Purchases
set Pending_Flag = 1
where purchases.cust_id = c1.cust_id;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: The tables Im using are the following 
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
 cust_id char(6) constraint customers_pk PRIMARY KEY,
 first_name varchar2(100),
 last_name varchar2(100),
 credit_line number(10,2),
 curr_balance number(10,2),
    earned_points number(5),
 tier_id char(2),
    constraint tier_fk foreign key (tier_id) references REWARDS_TIER,
    constraint balance_chk check (curr_balance <= credit_line)
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE PURCHASES(
 purchase_id char(7) constraint purchase_pk PRIMARY KEY,
 cust_id char(6),
 purchase_date date,
    purchase_amount number(10,2),
    pending_flag number(1), -- a value of 1 means it is pending
 constraint cust_pur_fk foreign key (cust_id) references CUSTOMERS
);

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: Really its the first time Im doing a Cursor Procedure so Im getting errors compiling it and second I don't know if what Im doing is correct.

Comment: A procedure without parameters is just that, you don't have anything in the () after the procedure name. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you posted `CREATE TABLE` statements within the question, not as comments. Besides, you didn't post all tables involved (those referenced by referential integrity constraints so I removed them):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE customers(
  2    cust_id         CHAR(6)
  3      CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  4    first_name      VARCHAR2(100),
  5    last_name       VARCHAR2(100),
  6    credit_line     NUMBER(10,2),
  7    curr_balance    NUMBER(10,2),
  8    earned_points   NUMBER(5),
  9    tier_id         CHAR(2)
 10  --  CONSTRAINT tier_fk FOREIGN KEY(tier_id)
 11  --    REFERENCES rewards_tier,
 12  --  CONSTRAINT balance_chk CHECK(curr_balance <= credit_line)
 13  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE purchases(
  2    purchase_id       CHAR(7)
  3      CONSTRAINT purchase_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  4    cust_id           CHAR(6),
  5    purchase_date     DATE,
  6    purchase_amount   NUMBER(10,2),
  7    pending_flag      NUMBER(1)
  8    -- a value of 1 means it is pending
  9  --  CONSTRAINT cust_pur_fk FOREIGN KEY(cust_id)
 10  --    REFERENCES customers
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Now, the procedure:

- it is missing `END LOOP` (so I added it)
- it contains one `BEGIN-END` pair that isn't necessary (so I removed it)
- cursor name is `c1`, but you don't reference columns it returns by cursor name - you have to use cursor variable name (`purchaserow`) instead

This compiles; you said that you don't know whether what you're doing is correct or not. How are we supposed to know it? You never explained what problem you're solving.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_balance AS
  2    CURSOR c1 IS
  3    SELECT purchases.cust_id,
  4           purchase_amount,
  5           curr_balance,
  6           credit_line,
  7           pending_flag
  8    FROM purchases
  9    INNER JOIN customers ON purchases.cust_id = customers.cust_id
 10    WHERE purchases.pending_flag = 1
 11    FOR UPDATE OF curr_balance;
 12
 13    pendingbalance       purchases.purchase_amount%TYPE;
 14    purchaserow          c1%rowtype;
 15    proposednewbalance   purchases.purchase_amount%TYPE;
 16  BEGIN
 17      OPEN c1;
 18      FETCH c1 INTO purchaserow;
 19      WHILE c1%found LOOP
 20        SELECT SUM(purchase_amount)
 21        INTO pendingbalance
 22        FROM purchases
 23        WHERE cust_id = purchaserow.cust_id -- this
 24              AND pending_flag = 1;
 25
 26    proposednewbalance := pendingbalance + purchaserow.curr_balance;
 27    IF proposednewbalance > purchaserow.credit_line THEN
 28      dbms_output.put_line('One or more purchases were not processed for     Customer');
 29    END IF;
 30    IF proposednewbalance <= purchaserow.credit_line THEN
 31      UPDATE customers
 32      SET
 33        curr_balance = proposednewbalance
 34      WHERE customers.cust_id = purchaserow.cust_id;  -- this
 35
 36    END IF;
 37
 38    IF proposednewbalance <= purchaserow.credit_line THEN
 39      UPDATE purchases
 40      SET
 41        pending_flag = 1
 42      WHERE purchases.cust_id = purchaserow.cust_id;
 43
 44    END IF;
 45  END LOOP; -- this
 46  END;
 47  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot thank you very much for this! So I assume I was on the right track just some bad syntax in some places then?

Comment: Littlefoot could I use your knowledge one more time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773756/solving-procedure-with-no-parameters